# Tokenising stream of HTTP messages in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, libcurl, tokenize, cfhttp

I have an `NSData` object that consists of several HTTP responses or requests concatenated together. What is the most effective way to tokenise this stream of requests/responses into individual `CFHTTPMessageRef` objects?

My current approach is to read the data one line at a time until `CFHTTPMessageIsHeaderComplete` returns `YES`, at which point I then grab the value of the `Content-Length` header to determine the length of the body associated with this particular request.

This approach works reasonably well, but fails in the case of [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). I could now add additional logic to deal with chunked transfers, but my parsing logic will grow more than I would like. Similarly, I am only currently dealing with well-formed messages -- it will trip up should a message not be formatted perfectly.

Is there (ideally) a set of Objective-C classes that can parse a stream of data into discrete HTTP messages? Is this something that `libcurl` could perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, libcurl cannot split up this for you. It only separates actual HTTP responses that it receives over the network.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I ended up factoring out the tokenising code and it wasn't too much of an issue. Was just wanting to see if I could get away with as little work as possible. :)